# Error creating bean with name 'log4jConfigurer' defined in class path resource [common-context.xml]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, log4j, noclassdeffounderror

I am using spring 4.x dependency jars in my spring boot 2.0.3 application and one of the classes in the jars depends on org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer

Below is the exception trace I get when starting the application

```
ERROR: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'log4jConfigurer' defined in class path resource [common-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1708)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:581)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer
    at com.xyz.common.util.config.XyzLog4jConfigurer.initializeLog4JConfigurer(XyzLog4jConfigurer.java:58)
    at com.xyz.common.util.config.XyzLog4jConfigurer.init(XyzLog4jConfigurer.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1833)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1776)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1704)
    ... 24 more
```

I have the following ivy configuration corresponding to the class in the dependent project's ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-core" rev="4.1.6" conf="compile->compile(*),master(*);runtime->runtime(*);all->default(*)"/>
```

I don't understand why does the error occur. Can someone help me fix this ?

Comment: Can you share bean initialization of that class?

Comment: <bean id="log4jConfigurer"
  class="com.xyz.common.util.config.XyzLog4jConfigurer"
  init-method="init" />

Comment: If you are using Spring 4.2.1+ then Log4jConfigurer is deprecated and should be changed for Apache Log4j 2 as per Spring documentation.

Comment: The dependent spring project's version is 4.1.6

Comment: Hmm, Spring does not see your class during runtime. Check your build process and startup commands.

Comment: From my understanding, while application  context is trying to load the bean from common-context.xml from dependent project which has a dependency of org/springframework/util/Log4jConfigurer an this dependent class is present in ivy.xml of the project as a part of the spring-core jar

Comment: Why should there be an issue in loading class from a dependent jar present in the project's ivy.xml. Am i missing some configuration here ?

Comment: Look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java). It might give you clarification.

Comment: Spring Boot requires Spring 5. So you cannot use Spring 4 based dependencies. In Spring 5 the `Log4jConfigurer` has been removed in Spring 5.

Comment: Oh thanks for the update. So can you please suggest me how to solve this ?

Comment: Will changing logging to apache commons fix this issue so that log4j configurer is not used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of spring boot version 2.0.3. I think Log4jConfigurer is deprecated in version 2.0. It was fixed by using spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE